# Convert raster PSD to vector and then import into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vector, raster

I worked with a graphic designer who created a few screens for me. He is giving me two things: a PSD of the screen and a folder containing each element on the screen as a PNG. Since I will have to import a lot of these screens, what's the quickest way to vectorize each element of the screen and quickly import into Android Studio? I'm new to Android Dev, so please be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

Png's can't be converted or can't be imported in android studio as vector. Please ask your designer to provide either vectors or Svg files of those images and import those svg's inside android studio as vector.

Comment: Wait are you sure that PNGs can't be converted? I see a ton of online resources to convert PNG to vector.

Comment: Yes online resources maybe available but you can not do it internally inside android studio. Also there is possibility that png's converted using online tools may not be  supported by Android studio. There is a little tags difference. So better way is to get Svgs by the designer and import them into android studio as vector. Right Click on drawable folder --> Then New --> Then Vector Asset -->Then import from computer local drive. -->Then select svg it will automatically convert that svg to vector asset